# Scale and Precision of NSDecimalNumber value

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsdecimalnumber

Let us suppose I have a variable `v` of type `NSDecimalNumber`

`let v = 34.596904` in its own format.

I want to know the precision and scale of this number, not the default one. I did not find any function in the `NSDecimalNumber` class which gives these values or maybe someone would like to throw some light on how it works.

```
precision = 8
scale = 6
```

precision is count of significant digits in number and scale is count of significant digit after decimal

Comment: What sort of values do you expect as `scale` or `precision`? They are not so common terms in various implementation of decimal types. You may need to explain what you expect, adding some example would be a good way.

Comment: integer values i.e. count of digits

Comment: Do you know `BigDecimal` in Java? And you want to get something similar to Java's `scale` or `precision`?

Comment: yes I was looking for same

Answer (score 1):

This extension will give you the specific value for your only example:

```
extension Decimal {
    var scale: Int {
        return -self.exponent
    }

    var precision: Int {
        return Int(floor(log10((self.significand as NSDecimalNumber).doubleValue)))+1
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let v: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: "34.596904")

print("precision=\((v as Decimal).precision)") //->precision=8
print("scale=\((v as Decimal).scale)") //->scale=6
```

But I cannot be sure if this generates expected results in all cases you have in mind, as you have shown only one example...

---

One more, in Swift, `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` are easily bridgeable and you should better use `Decimal` as far as you can.